# Any study about negative existentials?

Tags: polarity, existential

Context: polymorphic type theory, without dependent type theory features.

The conventional definition of existentials is positive, like in the intro of [this article on Jon Sterling's website](https://www.jonmsterling.com/papers/sterling-2022-existentials.pdf), recommended by Trebor.

I wonder if we can have a negative one, something like this:

$$
    \frac{
        Γ ⊢ u:∃x. α
    }{
        Γ ⊢ u.1~\text{type} \quad \text{and} \quad Γ ⊢ u.2:α[x := u.1]
    }
$$

This rule is also "compatible" with the introduction rule, say, we can get pretty sensible β laws out of it.

I noticed that all the resource I can find define existentials as positive. What is the insight behind this, beyond just being dual to universals? One reason I can think of is that it's the rule you get when you do the encoding based on universals, but that couldn't be all, right?

It may also be the case that positive existentials are just nonsense, too, but I'd also love to learn about some explanations!

I googled "negative existential" and "negative polarity existential type", didn't get helpful results.

Comment: Are you just trying to treat the existential the same as a Sigma type?  If so, isn’t the full Curry-Howard isomorphism where Type and Prop are the same or isomorphic one case where this works?  Of course then  you can’t have the proof irrelevance of Prop that is found in many systems.  (I might be totally mistaken on what you are asking.  I’m not an expert in type theory, and I also don’t understand why your existential is quantifying over Type.)

Comment: @JasonRute I'm thinking about existentials in the context of a polymorphic type theory instead of dependent type theory. So there's nothing as Sigma type.

Comment: I have seen existential types that work this way, although I'm struggling to find the papers covering them. Generally, though, the difference from Σ types is that there is no rule that $(T,t).1 = T$, because that would violate the intended abstraction. I think maybe Harper and Sterling's "Logical Relations as Types" might be a new paper that also works this way, but I find it impenetrable.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it should not break that abstraction...

Comment: As a related search term, I think this kind of existential is kind of essential for "applicative" ML functors. There you want it to be the case that types from separate applications $F(M)$ are actually recognized as the same type. These 'negative' existentials are the most natural way of talking about that, I think. Perhaps you could still do it with the positive version, but it'd be awkward. So, perhaps search for 'applicative functor' in the ML context. Also 'path dependent types' in the Scala context are essentially the same thing, I think.